# Java Tunnel HTTPS(SSL) Requests

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, proxy, tunnel

I am writing a java application to serve as a local proxy. I have been helped greatly by this piece of code from http://www.nsftools.com/tips/jProxy.java. See program below:

```
/* <!-- in case someone opens this in a browser... --> <pre> */
/*
 * This is a simple multi-threaded Java proxy server
 * for HTTP requests (HTTPS doesn't seem to work, because
 * the CONNECT requests aren't always handled properly).
 * I implemented the class as a thread so you can call it 
 * from other programs and kill it, if necessary (by using 
 * the closeSocket() method).
 *
 * We'll call this the 1.1 version of this class. All I 
 * changed was to separate the HTTP header elements with
 * \r\n instead of just \n, to comply with the official
 * HTTP specification.
 *  
 * This can be used either as a direct proxy to other
 * servers, or as a forwarding proxy to another proxy
 * server. This makes it useful if you want to monitor
 * traffic going to and from a proxy server (for example,
 * you can run this on your local machine and set the
 * fwdServer and fwdPort to a real proxy server, and then
 * tell your browser to use "localhost" as the proxy, and
 * you can watch the browser traffic going in and out).
 *
 * One limitation of this implementation is that it doesn't 
 * close the ProxyThread socket if the client disconnects
 * or the server never responds, so you could end up with
 * a bunch of loose threads running amuck and waiting for
 * connections. As a band-aid, you can set the server socket
 * to timeout after a certain amount of time (use the
 * setTimeout() method in the ProxyThread class), although
 * this can cause false timeouts if a remote server is simply
 * slow to respond.
 *
 * Another thing is that it doesn't limit the number of
 * socket threads it will create, so if you use this on a
 * really busy machine that processed a bunch of requests,
 * you may have problems. You should use thread pools if
 * you're going to try something like this in a "real"
 * application.
 *
 * Note that if you're using the "main" method to run this
 * by itself and you don't need the debug output, it will
 * run a bit faster if you pipe the std output to 'nul'.
 *
 * You may use this code as you wish, just don't pretend 
 * that you wrote it yourself, and don't hold me liable for 
 * anything that it does or doesn't do. If you're feeling 
 * especially honest, please include a link to nsftools.com
 * along with the code. Thanks, and good luck.
 *
 * Julian Robichaux -- http://www.nsftools.com
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class jProxy extends Thread
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;

    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private int thisPort = DEFAULT_PORT;
    private String fwdServer = "";
    private int fwdPort = 0;
    private int ptTimeout = ProxyThread.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
    private int debugLevel = 0;
    private PrintStream debugOut = System.out;


    /* here's a main method, in case you want to run this by itself */
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int port = 0;
        String fwdProxyServer = "";
        int fwdProxyPort = 0;

        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("USAGE: java jProxy <port number> [<fwd proxy> <fwd port>]");
            System.err.println("  <port number>   the port this service listens on");
            System.err.println("  <fwd proxy>     optional proxy server to forward requests to");
            System.err.println("  <fwd port>      the port that the optional proxy server is on");
            System.err.println("\nHINT: if you don't want to see all the debug information flying by,");
            System.err.println("you can pipe the output to a file or to 'nul' using \">\". For example:");
            System.err.println("  to send output to the file prox.txt: java jProxy 8080 > prox.txt");
            System.err.println("  to make the output go away: java jProxy 8080 > nul");
            return;
        }

        // get the command-line parameters
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if (args.length > 2)
        {
            fwdProxyServer = args[1];
            fwdProxyPort = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        }

        // create and start the jProxy thread, using a 20 second timeout
        // value to keep the threads from piling up too much
        System.err.println("  **  Starting jProxy on port " + port + ". Press CTRL-C to end.  **\n");
        jProxy jp = new jProxy(port, fwdProxyServer, fwdProxyPort, 20);
        jp.setDebug(1, System.out);     // or set the debug level to 2 for tons of output
        jp.start();

        // run forever; if you were calling this class from another
        // program and you wanted to stop the jProxy thread at some
        // point, you could write a loop that waits for a certain
        // condition and then calls jProxy.closeSocket() to kill
        // the running jProxy thread
        while (true)
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // if we ever had a condition that stopped the loop above,
        // we'd want to do this to kill the running thread
        //jp.closeSocket();
        //return;
    }


    /* the proxy server just listens for connections and creates
     * a new thread for each connection attempt (the ProxyThread
     * class really does all the work)
     */
    public jProxy (int port)
    {
        thisPort = port;
    }

    public jProxy (int port, String proxyServer, int proxyPort)
    {
        thisPort = port;
        fwdServer = proxyServer;
        fwdPort = proxyPort;
    }

    public jProxy (int port, String proxyServer, int proxyPort, int timeout)
    {
        thisPort = port;
        fwdServer = proxyServer;
        fwdPort = proxyPort;
        ptTimeout = timeout;
    }


    /* allow the user to decide whether or not to send debug
     * output to the console or some other PrintStream
     */
    public void setDebug (int level, PrintStream out)
    {
        debugLevel = level;
        debugOut = out;
    }


    /* get the port that we're supposed to be listening on
     */
    public int getPort ()
    {
        return thisPort;
    }


    /* return whether or not the socket is currently open
     */
    public boolean isRunning ()
    {
        if (server == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    /* closeSocket will close the open ServerSocket; use this
     * to halt a running jProxy thread
     */
    public void closeSocket ()
    {
        try {
            // close the open server socket
            server.close();
            // send it a message to make it stop waiting immediately
            // (not really necessary)
            /*Socket s = new Socket("localhost", thisPort);
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            os.write((byte)0);
            os.close();
            s.close();*/
        }  catch(Exception e)  { 
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println(e);
        }

        server = null;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        try {
            // create a server socket, and loop forever listening for
            // client connections
            server = new ServerSocket(thisPort);
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Started jProxy on port " + thisPort);

            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                ProxyThread t = new ProxyThread(client, fwdServer, fwdPort);
                t.setDebug(debugLevel, debugOut);
                t.setTimeout(ptTimeout);
                t.start();
            }
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("jProxy Thread error: " + e);
        }

        closeSocket();
    }

}


/* 
 * The ProxyThread will take an HTTP request from the client
 * socket and send it to either the server that the client is
 * trying to contact, or another proxy server
 */
class ProxyThread extends Thread
{
    private Socket pSocket;
    private String fwdServer = "";
    private int fwdPort = 0;
    private int debugLevel = 0;
    private PrintStream debugOut = System.out;

    // the socketTimeout is used to time out the connection to
    // the remote server after a certain period of inactivity;
    // the value is in milliseconds -- use zero if you don't want 
    // a timeout
    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;
    private int socketTimeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;


    public ProxyThread(Socket s)
    {
        pSocket = s;
    }

    public ProxyThread(Socket s, String proxy, int port)
    {
        pSocket = s;
        fwdServer = proxy;
        fwdPort = port;
    }


    public void setTimeout (int timeout)
    {
        // assume that the user will pass the timeout value
        // in seconds (because that's just more intuitive)
        socketTimeout = timeout * 1000;
    }


    public void setDebug (int level, PrintStream out)
    {
        debugLevel = level;
        debugOut = out;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // client streams (make sure you're using streams that use
            // byte arrays, so things like GIF and JPEG files and file
            // downloads will transfer properly)
            BufferedInputStream clientIn = new BufferedInputStream(pSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedOutputStream clientOut = new BufferedOutputStream(pSocket.getOutputStream());

            // the socket to the remote server
            Socket server = null;

            // other variables
            byte[] request = null;
            byte[] response = null;
            int requestLength = 0;
            int responseLength = 0;
            int pos = -1;
            StringBuffer host = new StringBuffer("");
            String hostName = "";
            int hostPort = 80;

            // get the header info (the web browser won't disconnect after
            // it's sent a request, so make sure the waitForDisconnect
            // parameter is false)
            request = getHTTPData(clientIn, host, false);
            requestLength = Array.getLength(request);

            // separate the host name from the host port, if necessary
            // (like if it's "servername:8000")
            hostName = host.toString();
            pos = hostName.indexOf(":");
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                try { hostPort = Integer.parseInt(hostName.substring(pos + 1)); 
                    }  catch (Exception e)  { }
                hostName = hostName.substring(0, pos);
            }

            // either forward this request to another proxy server or
            // send it straight to the Host
            try
            {
                if ((fwdServer.length() > 0) && (fwdPort > 0))
                {
                    server = new Socket(fwdServer, fwdPort);
                }  else  {
                    server = new Socket(hostName, hostPort);
                }
            }  catch (Exception e)  {
                // tell the client there was an error
                String errMsg = "HTTP/1.0 500\nContent Type: text/plain\n\n" + 
                                "Error connecting to the server:\n" + e + "\n";
                clientOut.write(errMsg.getBytes(), 0, errMsg.length());
            }

            if (server != null)
            {
                server.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
                BufferedInputStream serverIn = new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                BufferedOutputStream serverOut = new BufferedOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                // send the request out
                serverOut.write(request, 0, requestLength);
                serverOut.flush();

                // and get the response; if we're not at a debug level that
                // requires us to return the data in the response, just stream
                // it back to the client to save ourselves from having to
                // create and destroy an unnecessary byte array. Also, we
                // should set the waitForDisconnect parameter to 'true',
                // because some servers (like Google) don't always set the
                // Content-Length header field, so we have to listen until
                // they decide to disconnect (or the connection times out).
                if (debugLevel > 1)
                {
                    response = getHTTPData(serverIn, true);
                    responseLength = Array.getLength(response);
                }  else  {
                    responseLength = streamHTTPData(serverIn, clientOut, true);
                }

                serverIn.close();
                serverOut.close();
            }

            // send the response back to the client, if we haven't already
            if (debugLevel > 1)
                clientOut.write(response, 0, responseLength);

            // if the user wants debug info, send them debug info; however,
            // keep in mind that because we're using threads, the output won't
            // necessarily be synchronous
            if (debugLevel > 0)
            {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                debugOut.println("Request from " + pSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + 
                                    " on Port " + pSocket.getLocalPort() + 
                                    " to host " + hostName + ":" + hostPort + 
                                    "\n  (" + requestLength + " bytes sent, " + 
                                    responseLength + " bytes returned, " + 
                                    Long.toString(endTime - startTime) + " ms elapsed)");
                debugOut.flush();
            }
            if (debugLevel > 1)
            {
                debugOut.println("REQUEST:\n" + (new String(request)));
                debugOut.println("RESPONSE:\n" + (new String(response)));
                debugOut.flush();
            }

            // close all the client streams so we can listen again
            clientOut.close();
            clientIn.close();
            pSocket.close();
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error in ProxyThread: " + e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private byte[] getHTTPData (InputStream in, boolean waitForDisconnect)
    {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and return it as
        // a byte array
        // the waitForDisconnect parameter tells us what to do in case
        // the HTTP header doesn't specify the Content-Length of the
        // transmission
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("");
        return getHTTPData(in, foo, waitForDisconnect);
    }


    private byte[] getHTTPData (InputStream in, StringBuffer host, boolean waitForDisconnect)
    {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and return it as
        // a byte array, and also return the Host entry in the header,
        // if it's specified -- note that we have to use a StringBuffer
        // for the 'host' variable, because a String won't return any
        // information when it's used as a parameter like that
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        streamHTTPData(in, bs, host, waitForDisconnect);
        return bs.toByteArray();
    }


    private int streamHTTPData (InputStream in, OutputStream out, boolean waitForDisconnect)
    {
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("");
        return streamHTTPData(in, out, foo, waitForDisconnect);
    }

    private int streamHTTPData (InputStream in, OutputStream out, 
                                    StringBuffer host, boolean waitForDisconnect)
    {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and send it to
        // the designated OutputStream
        StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer("");
        String data = "";
        int responseCode = 200;
        int contentLength = 0;
        int pos = -1;
        int byteCount = 0;

        try
        {
            // get the first line of the header, so we know the response code
            data = readLine(in);
            if (data != null)
            {
                header.append(data + "\r\n");
                pos = data.indexOf(" ");
                if ((data.toLowerCase().startsWith("http")) && 
                    (pos >= 0) && (data.indexOf(" ", pos+1) >= 0))
                {
                    String rcString = data.substring(pos+1, data.indexOf(" ", pos+1));
                    try
                    {
                        responseCode = Integer.parseInt(rcString);
                    }  catch (Exception e)  {
                        if (debugLevel > 0)
                            debugOut.println("Error parsing response code " + rcString);
                    }
                }
            }

            // get the rest of the header info
            while ((data = readLine(in)) != null)
            {
                // the header ends at the first blank line
                if (data.length() == 0)
                    break;
                header.append(data + "\r\n");

                // check for the Host header
                pos = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("host:");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                    host.setLength(0);
                    host.append(data.substring(pos + 5).trim());
                }

                // check for the Content-Length header
                pos = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("content-length:");
                if (pos >= 0)
                    contentLength = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(pos + 15).trim());
            }

            // add a blank line to terminate the header info
            header.append("\r\n");

            // convert the header to a byte array, and write it to our stream
            out.write(header.toString().getBytes(), 0, header.length());

            // if the header indicated that this was not a 200 response,
            // just return what we've got if there is no Content-Length,
            // because we may not be getting anything else
            if ((responseCode != 200) && (contentLength == 0))
            {
                out.flush();
                return header.length();
            }

            // get the body, if any; we try to use the Content-Length header to
            // determine how much data we're supposed to be getting, because 
            // sometimes the client/server won't disconnect after sending us
            // information...
            if (contentLength > 0)
                waitForDisconnect = false;

            if ((contentLength > 0) || (waitForDisconnect))
            {
                try {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesIn = 0;
                    while ( ((byteCount < contentLength) || (waitForDisconnect)) 
                            && ((bytesIn = in.read(buf)) >= 0) )
                    {
                        out.write(buf, 0, bytesIn);
                        byteCount += bytesIn;
                    }
                }  catch (Exception e)  {
                    String errMsg = "Error getting HTTP body: " + e;
                    if (debugLevel > 0)
                        debugOut.println(errMsg);
                    //bs.write(errMsg.getBytes(), 0, errMsg.length());
                }
            }
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error getting HTTP data: " + e);
        }

        //flush the OutputStream and return
        try  {  out.flush();  }  catch (Exception e)  {}
        return (header.length() + byteCount);
    }


    private String readLine (InputStream in)
    {
        // reads a line of text from an InputStream
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
        int c;

        try
        {
            // if we have nothing to read, just return null
            in.mark(1);
            if (in.read() == -1)
                return null;
            else
                in.reset();

            while ((c = in.read()) >= 0)
            {
                // check for an end-of-line character
                if ((c == 0) || (c == 10) || (c == 13))
                    break;
                else
                    data.append((char)c);
            }

            // deal with the case where the end-of-line terminator is \r\n
            if (c == 13)
            {
                in.mark(1);
                if (in.read() != 10)
                    in.reset();
            }
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error getting header: " + e);
        }

        // and return what we have
        return data.toString();
    }

}
```

Problem is secure sites like "https://www.google.com" don't work. I have tried to tweak the code over and over again but all to no avail. I have gone through questions answered here and many more sites too but I just cant seem to get it to work. I would av posted links but I cant cos I dnt av enuf reputation yet.

Someone pls help me with what needs to be done to support Secure Sites(HTTPS).

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if I didn't ask the question the right way.I'm a newbie. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Default port for https is `443`. This is used if no port is specified in the URL, as is the case with the google site you give as an example. Try adjusting the code with this in mind.

Comment: Thanks Mick but I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: Could you then describe your problem in more detail? If you're accessing non-public https sites then you also need to take SSL certificates into account.